# Change JavaScript and delete old one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML-head i have this script included:

```
<script id="mode" type="text/javascript" src="article.js"></script>
```

With a button click I'd like to change the source of the script to customers.js so that it then looks like this:

```
<script id="mode" type="text/javascript" src="customers.js"></script>
```

The point is that I don't want the article.js to be included in my page then anymore, so I can't just use `.append()`.

So, click on the article button -> **only** article.js included, click on the customers button -> **only** customers.js included.

I tried to solve this with jQuery this way, but I doesn' seem to work...:

```
$("#btArticle").click(function(){
  $("#mode").attr("src","article.js");
});

$("#btCustomers").click(function(){
  $("#mode").attr("src","customers.js");
});
```

Do you know where my mistake is?

**Update:** There are methods with the same name in customers.js and article.js. So there's a onSave() method in both of them and when I clicked the customer button before, I want the onSave() method of customers.js to be executed, not the one in articles.js.

Comment: Even if you could do what you want, the change would only last until you refresh your page, is that what you want? Also, changing that src, doens't mean the new js will be loaded...

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to come up with a solution to a problem that probably shouldn't exist. What is this trying to circumvent?

Comment: It's working fine for me. Not that I'll use it in a real code.

Comment: Maybe I should've mentioned that there are methods in both files with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The point is that I don't want the article.js to be included in my page then anymore, so I can't just use `.append()`.

Once the script has been downloaded and evaluated, anything it leaves lying around will remain unless explicitly removed; they're not linked to the `script` element itself and removing it won't have any effect on them.

The only way to get rid of the stuff `article.js` leaves lying around is to remove or overwrite each and every thing it creates and keeps.

Concrete example:

```
// article.js
var foo = "bar";
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".stuff").click(function() {
        alert("You clicked stuff!");
    });
});
```

If the `article.js` listed above is processed, you can remove the `script` element that loaded it, and that will have **no** effect on the `foo` global variable or the event handler that it hooked up.

If you want to have scripts that you can unload, have them use the module pattern with a single global symbol they add by assigning to a property on `window`, e.g.:

```
// article.js
window.articleScript = (function() {
    var foo = "bar";
    jQuery(function($) {
        $(".stuff").bind("click.article", function() {
            alert("You clicked stuff!");
        });
    });

    function remove() {
        $(".stuff").unbind("click.article");
        try {
            delete window.articleScript;
        }
        catch (e) { // Early IEs throw incorrectly on the above
            window.articleScript = undefined;
        }
    }

    return {
        remove: remove
    };
})();
```

You can then remove it by doing this:

```
articleScript.remove();
```

---

Re your comment on the question:

> Maybe I should've mentioned that there are methods in both files with the same name.

If you have global function declarations in `customers.js` that use the same name as global function declarations in `articles.js`, when you load `customers.js`, it will replace those functions.

So if you have this in `articles.js`:

```
function foo() {
    alert("Articles!");
}
```

...and this in `customers.js`:

```
function foo() {
    alert("Customers!");
}
```

And you have a button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="foo();" value="Foo">
```

When you've loaded just `articles.js` and not `customers.js`, clicking that button gives you "Articles!". If you then load `customers.js`, clicking the button will give you "Customers!".

That works because the event handler *calls* `foo()`, but the event handler itself is *not* `foo`. The `onclick` attribute creates a hidden event handler for you. The equivalent jQuery would be:

```
$("input[type='button'][value='Foo']").click(function() {
    foo();
});
```

Note that just doing `.click(foo)` will do something very different: It will hook up the function that `foo` points to *at that moment* as the event handler. Even if you change what `foo` points to later (by loading `customers.js`), that won't change the fact that the old function is hooked up as a handler.

FWIW, from the question and your comments, I think I'd recommend sitting back and reviewing your strategy for this page/app. All of this swapping of code in and out and such seems like a design problem.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't know that the script-tag just loads the script. Well, in my article.js I have a lot of "normal" JavaScript-functions, too. How can I prevent them from getting executed when they are called from a HTML-button (e.g. onclick="onOk()")?

Comment: @Patrick: Wrap your script in a function as per the above, and use jQuery to hook up your events rather than `onxyz` attributes. If you use jQuery's nifty "event namespacing" (I did in my example above), you can remove all of the event handlers the script sets up pretty easily. Example of the latter: http://jsbin.com/ipivon

Comment: Thanks. But I originally used the `onanything` methods because I change the content of the HTML file via an AJAX request. So when I added an button with the id btBla my jQuery `$("#btBla").click()`-function wouldn't work anymore and I had no idea why. That's why I handeld everything with onClick-stuff.

Comment: @Patrick: I would re-evaluate your approach. I've added a bit to the answer to address the comment you added to the question. Best of luck with it,

Comment: I see... I probably should really think of a re-design. Thanks anyway, I've learned a lot about jQuery and JavaScript in general. :D

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually loading and running the respective scripts, you are just changing the source for that tag. Use `.getScript()` to load and run the appropriate JavaScript file:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/