# So i want to know how can i add and remove the scripts from a react app header

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a react app in which i want to integrate two chatbase bots  they have every thing same like source etc but having diffrent chatbot ids i want when the name is selected like math it should show the first and for every thing else oit should append the other i am trying it but not geting any luck  help will be appericated

```
useEffect(() => {
    const head = document.querySelector('head');

    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://www.chatbase.co/embed.min.js';
    script.setAttribute('domain', 'www.chatbase.co');
    script.setAttribute('chatbotId', name === 'math' ? "id" : 'id');
    script.defer = true;

    if (head) {
      head.append(script);
    }

    return () => {
      if (head) {
        const scriptElement = head.querySelector('script[src="https://www.chatbase.co/embed.min.js"]');
        head.removeChild(scriptElement);
      }
    };
```

Comment: You can add a `script` element (which will load and run its code) as shown in your post. You can also remove a `script` element as shown in your post. But see [the linked question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816687/change-javascript-and-delete-old-one), removing the `script` element has no effect whatsoever on the code it loaded. That code remains loaded and active. If you want to actually remove the code, you'll have to refresh the page.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    alert('ddd')

    let iframe = document.getElementById('chatbase-bubble-window');
    const newSrc = location.pathname.includes('physics')
      ? 'https://www.chatbase.co/chatbot-iframe/-_xqdddsdasdsafdd'
      : 'https://www.chatbase.co/chatbot-iframe/1adadasdsafrewqrkb';


    if (iframe.src !== newSrc) {
      iframe.src = newSrc;

    }


  }, [location.pathname])



actually when i navigate through the icon and src for the iframe changes i have to click twice to go back any idea why this happening it onlky haopens whrn src is changed